# What is the best practice for select many from a huge list (10k+ items)?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Provide a way to select and submit many items from a 10k+ list of items within a reasonable time.

I tried JSF's h:selectItems and h:selectManyListBox, took a lot of time to load the component. (30s)

p:dataTable with lazyLoading, pagination and multiple checkbox selection.
Load time is fast but when SelectAll is checked, any ajax request related to the datatable is super slow. (17s-20s)

Comment: Don't use 1 component. Split into using multiple. Search (lazy, server side), select, add to another list (known serverside) and 'submit' without the need to send all to the server again.

Comment: Use an AutoComplete with "mutliple=true" or some other component that allows you not to load 10K items to the browser DOM!

Comment: Any progress on this? http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive explains why you should be (I did not downvote yet)

Comment: Hey, I did split to two components p:datatable and p:selectBooleanButton (selectAll), the select all will clear all the datatable and make them marked at the managedBean. (to avoid posting huge data)